# Why Vue official example 'markdown' don't works in .vue file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using ES6 and migrate vue official `markdown` example to `.vue` file, but it doesn't update `this.input` value in `compiledMarkdown` computed method?

the result and the `.vue` code is here:

[image]

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea :value="input" @input="update"></textarea>
    <div v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash';
import marked from 'marked';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      input: '# hello'
    };
  },
  computed: {
    compiledMarkdown() {
      return marked(this.input, { sanitize: true });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: _.debounce((e) => {
      this.input = e.target.value;
    }, 300)
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
   ...
</style>
```

I know computed property can bind data vaule and automatically update, but why not here?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/rdjjpc7a/4243/ Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you shouldn't be using an arrow function here:

```
methods: {
  update: _.debounce((e) => {
    this.input = e.target.value;
  }, 300)
}
```

This will bind `this` to the wrong context - the context of module file that you are writing, not the component instance created from it. Use a normal function instead.

```
methods: {
  update: _.debounce(function(e) {
    this.input = e.target.value;
  }, 300)
}
```

Comment: you are right. I tried to `console.log(this)` in anonymous function, and it output `Object {default: Object, input: "# hello3"}`. The **default** object is the compoment instance, and I can view updated input value in **default.data.scopes[0]._this.input**. How to explain it? Whatever the `this` in arrow function bind to? Thanks~

Comment: And how the `this` in anonymous function can bind to current compoment instance?

Comment: `this` in an arrow function is the current executing scope that the function is defined in. SO comments are not the right place to explain this in detail, you should read up on it, e.g. here: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#arrow-functions

Comment: I had read the introduce of arrow function in `You Dont Know JS`, but it seems to not sovle my puzzle above.